# mdadm.conf, `PROGRAM` arguments documentation

Tags: linux, configuration, raid, mdadm

I want to write a bash script that i can pass as the "PROGRAM" in the mdadm config file.
But i cant find what possible arguments get passed to the program.

Where can i find the documentation for that?

I found a example script here: https://www.suse.com/de-de/support/kb/doc/?id=000016716 but no explanation nor a list of possible arguments/values

Comment: check MONITOR MODE section of mdadm man page ...

Comment: @frostschutz Nice, Thanks.